# Google Translate cannot read a .pdf made in LaTeX

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, latex, translation

I have received a .pdf document from a colleague who uses LaTeX (I use Office products and have no knowledge of LaTeX at all). The document however is written in German, a language I speak, but not fluently, so there are parts of the text I need help with. However if I attempt to copy parts and then paste them on e.g. Google translate, the character-spacing between words is deleted, effectively stacking the words one after another. GTranslate cannot then recognise these properly and as a result, it cannot translate. Is there a way to go around this? Perhaps, by converting the .pdf to another format (that a Windows user like myself can do)? Also, I've mentioned the problem to my colleague and he couldn't figure out a solution to this, so I'd appreciate any hints as to what I can do (rather than things he could try using LaTeX). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems this may be a common problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28066/problem-copying-text-from-pdf-spaces-being-stripped http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69176/weird-behaviour-of-copying-no-space-between-words?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't familiar with LaTeX, but the files are essentially plain text. If the author sent you a copy of the LaTeX source, you could open them in Notepad or a similar program, and copy the text from there.